# Trying to subtract in pivot table isntead of sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to instead of using `np.sum` trying to use `np.subtract` in the pivot `aggfunc` parameter.
Using `np.sum` works.

However, when I use `np.subtract`, I get an error stating:

> **ufunc() missing 1 of 2required positional argument(s)**

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.subtract)
```

Lets say, hypothetically I got the following data sample:

```
A    B      C    D 
Bar  one  small  1 
Bar  one  large -2 
Bar  one  large  2 
Bar  two  small -3 
Bar  two  small -3 
TER  one  large  4 
TER  one  small -5
```

Above the bar one large using np.sum would net zero.
I need to subtract so it nets : `-4: -2 - 2 = -4`

Is there a way to subtract instead of sum?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: added the dataframe example =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick - multiple all duplicated rows by `-1` and then use `sum`:

```
df['D'] *= np.where(df.duplicated(['A','B','C']), -1, 1)
print (df)
     A    B      C  D
0  Bar  one  small  1
1  Bar  one  large -2
2  Bar  one  large -2
3  Bar  two  small -3
4  Bar  two  small  3
5  TER  one  large  4
6  TER  one  small -5

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc='sum')
print (table)
C        large  small
A   B                
Bar one   -4.0    1.0
    two    NaN    0.0
TER one    4.0   -5.0
```

Comment: that will mutate my data incorreectly though. BAR ONE LARGE wont give -4 and TER ONE SMALL wont stay -5

Comment: @pybianco - You are rigth, added column `C` to `duplicated.`

Comment: @pybianco - If ned something else, please add expected output from sample data.